# Unexpected behaviour for right click in Google Colab

Tags: google-chrome, google-colaboratory

I want to download files from a Google Colab notebook using the GUI. However, right-click on files won't open the specific Google menu allowing me to do it. Instead, it will open standard Chrome menu.

In other cases, like Google Drive, I'll be able to access this functionality. What's going on?

Thanks!

PD: Using MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and Chrome 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) (64-bit).

[image]

Comment: same issue here

Answer (score 0):

You need to download by code.

```
from google.colab import files
files.download('mnist_train_small.csv')
```